# How can I animate UILabels from an array to move across the screen with an equal delay between them?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uiviewanimation, animatewithduration

I have an array of UILabels that I want to animate across the screen. I am iterating though the array using  a for loop like below:

```
for(int i=0; i<[self.onScreenLabels count]; i++)
{
    UILabel *label = self.onScreenLabels[i];

    int x = label.frame.origin.x;
    int y = label.frame.origin.y;

    label.center=CGPointMake(320, 0);
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:1.0 options:0 animations:^{

    label.center=CGPointMake(x, y);

} completion:^(BOOL finished){

}];

}
```

I want each UILabel to delay 1.0 second after the last before animating, e.g. wait 1 second, fire the first, wait 1 second fire the second, wait 1 second fire the third ....etc all the way to the end of the array. However using this code there is a 1 second delay but ALL the labels then animate at the same time. Why is this? Is there a way around it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay is relative to the time at which you create the animation, so, because all of the animations are created at the same time in the loop they all have the same delay.

Instead, set the delay to the iteration index (`i`):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:i options:0 animations:^{ ...
```

so the first will start at 0, the second at 1, the third at 2, etc

(or `(i + 1)` if you prefer)

Comment: I actually tried something like this before, but it didn't work and the delay between them just got bigger and bigger. I tried it again now though and put i++ INSIDE the block (i needs to be a weak block var __block int i) and that fixed the problem! Makes sense now. Thank you!!!!!!

Comment: why is it though all the animations are created at the same time in the loop?

Comment: You should not need `i++` inside the block. `animateWithDuration:` returns immediately, it doesn't block the caller until the animation has completed so all of the iterations of the loop run 'at the same time'.

Comment: my bad, it makes no difference where it is placed. Why are all the animations created at the same time thought? I understand it as the first element of the UILabel is animated and finished and then the loop iterates through the second element of the array and does that animation and so on...

Comment: Each iteration of the loop just creates and starts the animations - it doesn't wait for them to complete...

Answer (score 0):

Use delay like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:i + 1.0 options:0 animations:^{
```

This will delay first label for 1 second and each later will be delayed for +1 second